# How can I include duplicate form data values in an Axios request?

Tags: javascript, typescript, http, axios, google-forms

I am trying to imitate a request to a Google Forms endpoint by examining request date on actual form submissions.  In the form data, Google makes a request with duplicate values to represent multiple options selected on the same entry, i.e.

```
entry.1111 = 1
entry.1111 = 2
entry.1111 = 3
```

To represent the data in my TS application with Axios, my request data is a JS object which of course cannot have duplicate properties.  It looks like this.

```
{
  entry.1111: [1, 2, 3]
}
```

My Axios request looks like this

```js
const body = toJS(entryPostParams);
Axios({
  method: 'post',
  url: surveyType === "preSurvey" ? PRE_FORM_RESPONSE_URL : POST_FORM_RESPONSE_URL,
  data: qs.stringify(body),
  headers: {
    'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8'
  }
}).then((err) => {
  console.log('err: ', err);
})
```

What is a simple and effective way to format the data such that I can include duplicate form data values in my request?

Answer (score 0):

Axios accepts [form data](https://www.npmjs.com/package/form-data) objects in the data property.  In my case I simply iterated over the key-value pairs in my `body` object and iterated over each value that was an array to add elements to the form data.